# XAML Variables displayed in TextBlock

Tags: c#, xaml, textblock

I am a complete newb into XAML.  I have previously worked with C#, C++, and ASP.net however if that helps.  Here is what I want to do; dynamically display a string variable (lets call it "debt") that is declared in the c# code behind.  Is there a simple way to do this using a TextBlock call?

Comment: You should learn about databinding and MVVM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code behind:

`TextBox.Text = debt;`

Answer (score 3):

You should use the Binding in WPF, of course you can do it in the code behind but what if your variable debt changed for any reason.

### Code Behind

Declare a dependency property like the code below, it'll auto implement the NotifyPropertyChanged wich will update your UI in case your variable value changed at runtime.

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public string Debt
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(DebtProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DebtProperty, value); }
        }


        public static readonly DependencyProperty DebtProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Debt", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
            this.Debt = "Test";
        }
    }
```

### XAML

And then in your Xaml just declare your textblock (or textbox if you want to modify the variable debt) and bind its Text property to your variable Debt.

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Debt, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

It seems to be a lot of code for just setting a text property but it's always better to user WPF binding.

Even better you can use MVVM pattern.